# how to convert Qstring to Long?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I am new to Qt Creator. I would like to convert a `QString` value into a `long` number. How would I do this?

```
long s;
QString x = "6458621237";
```

EDIT

As a result I'll have `long s = 6458621237`;

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the [toLong](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toLong) function.

For example,

```
 QString str = "FF";
 bool ok;

 long hex = str.toLong(&ok, 16);     // hex == 255, ok == true
 long dec = str.toLong(&ok, 10);     // dec == 0, ok == false
```

Comment: @sunset: It's in the documentation: "which is 10 by default and must be between 2 and 36, or 0. Returns 0 if the conversion fails."

Answer (score 5):

From the QT [Docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toLong):

> long QString::toLong ( bool * ok = 0, int base = 10 ) const
>
> Returns the string converted to a long using base base, which is 10 by
>   default and must be between 2 and 36 or 0. If base is 0, the base is
>   determined automatically using the following rules: If the string
>   begins with "0x", it is assumed to be hexadecimal; If it begins with
>   "0", it is assumed to be octal; Otherwise it is assumed to be decimal.
>   Returns 0 if the conversion fails.
>
> If ok is not 0: if a conversion error occurs, *ok is set to FALSE;
>   otherwise *ok is set to TRUE.
>
> Leading and trailing whitespace is ignored by this function.

Comment: I don't understand why people downvote you for a correct answer ?

Answer (score 0):

```
long s; 
QString x="6458621237";
s = x.toLong();
```